# Visual Studio error trying to start a new MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

[image: MVC 3 error]

I've uninstalled and reinstalled MVC 3 as well as repairing my VS 2010 install.  Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the OFFICIAL solution was that I had to get another Windows profile created...for some reason my old one was corrupt and somehow that affected everything, dont know how but when I login with the new profile everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling and doing a fresh install and it seems to have corrected the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally got it working.  Unfortunately there is no clear solution I can explain.  I had a friend send me a blank MVC 3 project he created.  When I opened it the first time I got a fit of errors and it ended up crashing my VS.  I restarted it and went to open it again and it worked!  I was then able to create a new project without error.  I jigged something loose I guess